# NixOS beginner: xmonad and haskellmode in NixOS 14.04

Tags: xmonad, nixos

I'm trying so set up a NixOS VM for code development in haskell, and got into troubles with the basic installation of both xmonad and emacs. The relevant part of my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` is

```
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    emacs
    emacs24Packages.haskellMode
    xlibs.xmessage
    haskellPackages.haskellPlatform.ghc
    haskellPackages.xmobar
    haskellPackages.xmonad
    haskellPackages.xmonadContrib
    haskellPackages.xmonadExtras
];
```

- xmonad: when I try to compile the code, xmonad complains that it couldn't find the module XMonad.Util.EZConfig.
  Compiling `xmonad.hs` with ghc is ok, and I'm also able to load the module into ghci.
  On the #nixos channel, I was told to use the function ghcWithPackages, but I wasn't able to correct the problem. Moreover, I'd like to understand why there is this problem in the first place, as it seems to me that this is a very simple use case. A minimal `xmonad.hs` with which I have the problem is:

  ```
  import XMonad
  import XMonad.Util.EZConfig

  main = xmonad $ defaultConfig
    { modMask = mod4Mask
    , terminal = "konsole"
    }
    `additionalKeysP`
    [ ("M-e", spawn "emacs")
    , ("M-f", spawn "firefox")
    ]
  ```
- emacs: after the installation of the package haskellmode (look at the configuration.nix above), I'm not able to enter haskell-mode in emacs.

I put together these problems as I suspect they're both caused by a fundamental incomprehension of something on my behalf, so the cause may be common.

Answer (score 4):

just add

```
    windowManager.xmonad.enableContribAndExtras = true;
```

to

```
    /etc/nixos/configuration.nix
```

Then start xmonad the usual way through your .xsession file

Answer (score 2):

I can't add comment for now... But I think it's a problem with cabal local and global repositories.

As I see, "Nix allows users to install packages without requiring root privileges, and provides each user with **its own view of the set of installed packages**. Multiple versions of a program or library can be installed at the same time. Package upgrades are atomic and can be rolled back."

Maybe you can use `ghc-pkg list` to see if, in root and normal user, the packages are well installed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In the end I solved this with the help of the kind guys on #nixos. The point was that I had to add the line `windowManager.xmonad.enableContribAndExtras = true;`. This is because the packages installed in ghc are kept separate from those needed by xmonad to permit the installation of xmonad even without all the haskell infrastructure

Comment: @meditans - if you turn this comment into an answer and mark it as accepted it'll help make it clear the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

I am unsure why you're unable to compile that... I can't offer a solution, but personally, I am able to compile my XMonad config which includes

```hs
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig
```

This is the relevant lines in my configuration.

```hs
    environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
      haskellPackages.xmobar
      haskellPackages.xmonad
      haskellPackages.xmonad-contrib
      haskellPackages.xmonad-extras
    ];

    programs.dconf.enable = true;

    services = {
      dbus = {
        enable = true;
        packages = [ pkgs.dconf ];
      };

      xserver = {
        enable = true;

        libinput = {
          enable = true;
          touchpad.disableWhileTyping = true;
        };

        serverLayoutSection = ''
          Option "StandbyTime" "0"
          Option "SuspendTime" "0"
          Option "OffTime"     "0"
        '';

        displayManager = {
          defaultSession = "none+xmonad";
          lightdm.enable = true;
          lightdm.greeters.mini.enable = true;
        };

        windowManager.xmonad = {
          enable = true;
          enableContribAndExtras = true;
        };

        xkbOptions = "caps:ctrl_modifier";
      };
    };

    env = {
      XMONAD_CONFIG_DIR = "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/xmonad";
      XMONAD_CACHE_DIR = "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/xmonad";
      XMONAD_DATA_DIR = "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/xmonad";
    };
```

As someone pointed out, it might be because you don't have the line:

```hs
enableContribAndExtras = true;
```

I posted my configuration also so you could see how this would tie into a more extensive configuration, in this case for lightdm.