# Could not find module ‘XMonad’

Tags: nixos, xmonad

I have a fresh NixOS installation, and I want to use my custom XMonad configuration. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
$ xmonad --recompile
XMonad will use ghc to recompile, because "/home/amy/.xmonad/build" does not exist.
Error detected while loading xmonad configuration file: /home/amy/.xmonad/xmonad.hs

xmonad.hs:1:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
1 | import XMonad
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here are the relevant parts of my configuration.nix:

```
  # List packages installed in system profile. To search, run:
  # $ nix search wget
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    bash
    dmenu2
    dzen2
    emacs
    firefox
    gitAndTools.gitFull
    haskellPackages.xmonad
    haskellPackages.xmonad-contrib
    haskellPackages.xmonad-extras
    gcc
    ghc
    stack
    x11
    xmonad-with-packages
    xorg.libX11
    xsel
    wget
  ];

  . . .

  services.xserver = {
    enable = true;
    layout = "ie";
    windowManager.xmonad = {
      enable = true;
      enableContribAndExtras = true;
      extraPackages = haskellPackages: [
        haskellPackages.xmonad
        haskellPackages.xmonad-contrib
        haskellPackages.xmonad-extras
      ];
    };
  };
#  windowManager.default = "xmonad";
```

I have read [NixOS beginner: xmonad and haskellmode in NixOS 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23740373/663299), but I already have `windowManager.xmonad.enableContribAndExtras = true;` in my configuration.nix.

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, I am on NixOS, but I am not using Nix to build my XMonad configuration. I am doing things the ordinary XMonad way: I have a `.xmonad` directory with my configuration in `xmonad.hs`, and I am running `xmonad --recompile` to build it.

**EDIT:** When I look for the relevant packages as root, I find them.

```
# nix-env -q
xmonad-0.14.2
xmonad-contrib-0.14
xmonad-extras-0.14
```

But as an ordinary user, the following command returns nothing.

```
$ nix-env -q
```

How do I make these packages visible to a non-root account?

**EDIT**: Strangely, when I rebooted, XMonad magically worked, compiling my configuration without problems. I don't know why rebooting helped, because I'd done nixos-rebuild switch several times.

Comment: Could you include the output of `ghc-pkg list`? It probably won't show XMonad. You probably need to add `ghc` with packages as described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377748/how-can-i-install-a-haskell-library-to-be-accessible-via-ghci-with-nixos

Comment: I think the way XMonad is packaged on Nixos is really convoluted. If you build it independently it's a lot easier to understand imo. I followed this guide: https://functor.tokyo/blog/2018-02-16-setup-xmonad-on-nixos

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski thank you for your suggestions; I learned a lot from them. Strangely, when I rebooted, XMonad magically worked, compiling my configuration without problems. I don't know why rebooting helped, because I'd done `nixos-rebuild switch` several times. But if you'd like to turn your comments into an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: No worries glad to hear it's working. Possibly it was recompiling the old config / executable somehow.

Comment: As an aside, `nix-env -q` only shows packages installed into that profile. So `nix-env -q` as a user won't show you programs that root installed using `nix-env -i` even though those programs in your `$PATH`, and even `root` won't see packages that are were installed via `environment.systemPackages`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but this search keep appearing on tops

The reason why this happens is because you installed xmonad twice

First one is just xmonad without any knowledge of other packages on your environment (that's the whole purpose of nix, remember, building **isolated** *and reproducible environments*)

```
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    ...
    haskellPackages.xmonad
    ...
  ];
```

The second one is installed by enabling the service, and is called [vanilla](https://web.archive.org/web/20210830083224if_/https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/services/x11/window-managers/xmonad.nix#L13) A.K.A `xmonad-with-packages` on the service configuration file:

```
services.xserver = {
    windowManager.xmonad = {
      enable = true;
    };
  };
```

[xmonad-with-packages](https://web.archive.org/web/20210830083229/https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/applications/window-managers/xmonad/wrapper.nix) is actually a [wrapper script](https://web.archive.org/web/20210830083512/https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/build-support/setup-hooks/make-wrapper.sh) that sets the needed environment variables so that xmonad can see the `extraPackages` you added

## TLDR:

1. Both packages output an `xmonad` binary
2. First one has no access to your env
3. Second one does
4. When you run `xmonad --recompile`, the first one is ran, no luck
5. When xserver runs `xmonad` it is actually running the `vanilla` binary from `xmonad-with-packages` (plus your `extraPackages`) (See code below, and [link here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210830083224if_/https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/services/x11/window-managers/xmonad.nix#L36))

```
  xmonad = if (cfg.config != null) then xmonad-config else xmonad-vanilla;
```

This is for nixpkgs, but i just had the same problem with `home-manager` since a few days

## Proof

Inspecting `xmonad`

```
which xmonad

/home/hao/.nix-profile/bin/xmonad
```

I know it’s in my profile…, but where?

```
which xmonad | xargs readlink

/nix/store/yx0kb7i209ffh20qmxpbvmllb32lq7rr-home-manager-path/bin/xmonad
```

Ok…, installed by `home-manager`, but where is it?

```
which xmonad | xargs readlink | xargs readlink

/nix/store/g7f0v21jmi9smh1q1f6fw050r76nzb1p-ghc-8.10.6-with-packages/bin/xmonad
```

Is it really xmonad or a symlink?

```
file /nix/store/g7f0v21jmi9smh1q1f6fw050r76nzb1p-ghc-8.10.6-with-packages/bin/xmonad

/nix/store/g7f0v21jmi9smh1q1f6fw050r76nzb1p-ghc-8.10.6-with-packages/bin/xmonad: symbolic link to /nix/store/0lxxi3hrs49fiil29xw6gjx09ad3nf2n-xmonad-0.15/bin/xmonad
```

Is it really xmonad or a symlink? x2

```
file /nix/store/0lxxi3hrs49fiil29xw6gjx09ad3nf2n-xmonad-0.15/bin/xmonad

/nix/store/0lxxi3hrs49fiil29xw6gjx09ad3nf2n-xmonad-0.15/bin/xmonad: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /nix/store/9bh3986bpragfjmr32gay8p95k91q4gy-glibc-2.33-47/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped
```

^ Save that path, you can see it’s actually pointing to the `xmonad` binary:

Now enter the monad (with packages):

```
nix-shell -p xmonad-with-packages
```

For starters, the derivation is pointing elsewhere, not to my home-environment,
but directly to the nix-store:

```
which xmonad

/nix/store/6n1wh9ky7ydbd2ii5877nly9xbrqz4m9-xmonad-with-packages-8.10.6/bin/xmonad
```

And we now see not a binary file but a bash script

```
file /nix/store/6n1wh9ky7ydbd2ii5877nly9xbrqz4m9-xmonad-with-packages-8.10.6/bin/xmonad

/nix/store/6n1wh9ky7ydbd2ii5877nly9xbrqz4m9-xmonad-with-packages-8.10.6/bin/xmonad: a /nix/store/dpjnjrqbgbm8a5wvi1hya01vd8wyvsq4-bash-4.4-p23/bin/bash -e script, ASCII text executable
```

And if you look at the contents, you’ll see that it's actually using the same
xmonad from above (see below, what does `exec` runs), except it adds all the `extraPackages` (the `NIX_GHC` path) for us:

```
which xmonad | xargs cat


! /nix/store/dpjnjrqbgbm8a5wvi1hya01vd8wyvsq4-bash-4.4-p23/bin/bash -e
export NIX_GHC='/nix/store/sca07cyap7rqkxk4c7sqkvn94bsfaaiz-ghc-8.10.6-with-packages/bin/ghc'
export XMONAD_XMESSAGE='/nix/store/jg3adhj3kpqm8dcrgb95nn5c5k5z61yx-xmessage-1.0.5/bin/xmessage'
exec "/nix/store/sca07cyap7rqkxk4c7sqkvn94bsfaaiz-ghc-8.10.6-with-packages/bin/xmonad"  "@"
```

What does `exec` run?

```
file /nix/store/sca07cyap7rqkxk4c7sqkvn94bsfaaiz-ghc-8.10.6-with-packages/bin/xmonad

/nix/store/sca07cyap7rqkxk4c7sqkvn94bsfaaiz-ghc-8.10.6-with-packages/bin/xmonad: symbolic link to /nix/store/0lxxi3hrs49fiil29xw6gjx09ad3nf2n-xmonad-0.15/bin/xmonad
```

Let’s compile

```
xmonad --recompile

XMonad will use ghc to recompile, because "/home/hao/.xmonad/build" does not exist.
XMonad recompilation process exited with success!
```

But out of our safe space first

```
exit
```

Using our `home-manager` derivation

```
xmonad --recompile 2>&1

XMonad will use ghc to recompile, because "/home/hao/.xmonad/build" does not exist.
Error detected while loading xmonad configuration file: /home/hao/.xmonad/xmonad.hs

xmonad.hs:4:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad’
    Perhaps you meant DsMonad (needs flag -package-key ghc-8.10.6)
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
4 | import           XMonad                                 hiding (config,workspaces)
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:8:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
8 | import           XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:9:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
9 | import           XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:10:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.StackSet’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
10 | import qualified XMonad.StackSet                 as W
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:11:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.ManageHook’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
11 | import           XMonad.ManageHook
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:12:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Util.NamedScratchpad’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
12 | import           XMonad.Util.NamedScratchpad
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:13:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Util.EZConfig’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
13 | import           XMonad.Util.EZConfig
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:14:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Actions.CycleWS’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
14 | import           XMonad.Actions.CycleWS                        (shiftTo, moveTo, Direction1D(..), WSType(..))
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:15:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Actions.Commands’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
15 | import           XMonad.Actions.Commands
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:16:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Actions.ShowText’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
16 | import           XMonad.Actions.ShowText
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:17:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Layout.Fullscreen’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
17 | import           XMonad.Layout.Fullscreen
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:18:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Layout.NoBorders’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
18 | import           XMonad.Layout.NoBorders
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:19:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
19 | import           XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:20:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Actions.CopyWindow’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
20 | import           XMonad.Actions.CopyWindow
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:22:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Actions.Navigation2D’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
22 | import           XMonad.Actions.Navigation2D
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:23:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Util.Run’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
23 | import           XMonad.Util.Run                               (spawnPipe)
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:24:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Util.NamedWindows’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
24 | import           XMonad.Util.NamedWindows                      (getName, unName)
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:27:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Util.ExtensibleState’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
27 | import qualified XMonad.Util.ExtensibleState     as XS
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:28:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Util.Timer’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
28 | import           XMonad.Util.Timer
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:31:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Actions.UpdateFocus’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
31 | import           XMonad.Actions.UpdateFocus
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:32:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Layout.SimpleFloat’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
32 | import           XMonad.Layout.SimpleFloat
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:33:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Layout.PerWorkspace’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
33 | import           XMonad.Layout.PerWorkspace                    (onWorkspace)
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:34:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Layout.Magnifier’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
34 | import           XMonad.Layout.Magnifier         as Mag
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:35:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Util.Loggers’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
35 | import           XMonad.Util.Loggers
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:36:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Layout.LayoutCombinators’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
36 | import           XMonad.Layout.LayoutCombinators               (JumpToLayout(..))
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:39:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Actions.FloatSnap’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
39 | import           XMonad.Actions.FloatSnap
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:40:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Util.WorkspaceCompare’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
40 | import qualified XMonad.Util.WorkspaceCompare    as W
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:42:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad.Layout.Gaps’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
42 | import           XMonad.Layout.Gaps
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Please check the file for errors.
```